# New to nethack: playing wizard

Tags: nethack

The top question on this website is about nethack so being a total baller I downloaded the game. I got the visual version for windows. I want to play a wizard but I died on my first attempt. I wonder if it had something to do  with me not being able to use spells. I have no idea how to play this game so I wonder what are some useful commands. (i learned that D lets you drop things) and how to generally play each class.

It doesnt need to get into the specifics  I just want to learn the basics so i dont keep dying (although tricks are appreciated as well)

Comment: Use `Z` (that's `shift-z`) to cast spells.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Read the ingame help with `?`, especially `?a`, to get acquainted with the very basics.
- If that was too dry, also check out the longer form [Nethack Guidebook](http://www.nethack.org/v343/Guidebook.html).
- Decide if you want a spoiler-free experience, or if you'd rather have all games mechanics and messages explained to you through, e.g., the [Nethack Wiki](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Main_Page)

Oh, by the way. You *are* going to keep dying. A lot. The only alternative to death is (spoiler alert!) victory and only **1.43%** of all games played on public server nethack.alt.org result in victory (source: [1](http://alt.org/nethack/dailygames_ct.html), [2](http://alt.org/nethack/dailyasc_ct.html)), so get used to it :)

Comment: There's another alternative - climbing out of the dungeon without the Amulet.  Gets you about a 10% higher score than dying.